# unknown reason for html body overflowing

Tags: html, css

so I'm building a site for a class and i have a unexpected probalem with the css. at smaller sizes the body seems to expand beyond the viewport. Having set the body width to be `100vw` and `100%` with nothing changing, I can't see why this would be happening?

you might have to copy-paste the snippet into a codepen. Stack wouldn't let me link to a codepen :(

anyways anything you can tell me to fix would help!

```css
body{
    
    width:100vw;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;

        
}
.page-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 0.5fr repeat(3, 2fr) 0.5fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto 0em repeat(2, auto);
    grid-template-areas: "header header header header header"
                         ". . . . ."
                         ". main main main ."
                         "footer footer footer footer footer";
}

.header{
    display:flex;
    position:relative;

    align-items: center;

    flex-direction:column;



    height:80vh;
    grid-area: header;

    color:white
}

.navbar{ 
    display: flex;
    
    margin-top:8%;

    width:70%;
    
    
    justify-content: center;
}


.nav-item{
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin: 0em 0.2em;
}

.dot{
    margin-right: 0.15em;
}
.dot.first, .dot.last{
    
}


.title-welcome{
    margin-top:1.5em;
    padding:0 1em;
    font-size:3rem;
    text-align: center;
}



.header_video-wrapper{
    grid-area: header;
    
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow:none;
}

.header_video-overlay{
   opacity:0.4;
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:100%; 
}

.header_video{
    position:absolute;
}


.main_content{
    grid-area: main;
    height:auto;

    /* adds a break between sections */
    padding-top:2em;
}
.footer{
    height:4rem;
    grid-area:footer;
}

/*placeholder classes are just for grid demonstration*/
.placeholder{
    width:100%;
    background-color: grey;
}


@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    

    .page_container{

        grid-template-columns: 0.5fr repeat(3, 2fr) 0.5fr;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(3, auto) 14rem;
        grid-template-areas:"header header header header header header header header"
                            ". carousel carousel carousel carousel carousel carousel ."
                            ". main main main main main main ."
                            "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer";

    }


    .header{
        height: 45vh
    }

    .navbar{
    
    }

    .nav-item{
            
    }

    .dot.first, .dot.last{
        /* display:none; */
    }

    .main_content{

    }

    .footer{

    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Truro Multicultural Festival</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles-index.css" type="text/css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="header">
            <nav class="navbar">
                <div class="nav-item">
                    <div>
                        <span class="dot first">•</span>
                        <a href="" class="page_link">Home</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item">
                    <div>
                        <span class="dot">•</span>
                        <a href="/about" class="page_link">About</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item">
                    <div>
                        <span class="dot">•</span>
                        <a href="/events" class="page_link">Events</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-item">
                    <div>
                        <span class="dot">•</span>
                        <a href="/contact" class="page_link">Contact</a>
                        <span class="dot last">•</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <h1 class="title-welcome">
                Welcome To The Truro Multicultural Festival
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="header_video-wrapper" preload="none">
            <div class="header_video-overlay"></div>
            <video class="header_video" src="media/header-video.webm"></video>
        </div>


        <main class="main_content placeholder"></main>
        <footer class="footer placeholder"></footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The content (the text of the four links) doesn't break into new lines: when they are all in one line they are certainly rather wide and that gives your HTML content a wider width than the browser window.

Either let the content fit (smaller text), wrap the content at thinner widths (media query), or hide overflow content by adding overflow: hidden to .page-wrapper (or .header).

Comment: just saw the edit you made; this solves it. thanks man, I appreciate the assistance!

Comment: @Leviathan_the_Great no problem, accept the answer and let me know what method you went with (just out of curiosity).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the `overflow:` css property to change how your text wraps, the text not wrapping is causing the element to expand larger than expected.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow